# Are SQL Server 2008 Table Valued Parameters vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-injection, table-valued-parameters

I have been investigating Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008, and I've discovered that when passing such a parameter to a stored procedure, a query such as the following is sent to the database server:

```
declare @p1 dbo.MyTypeName
insert into @p1 values(N'row1col1',N'row1col2')
insert into @p1 values(N'row2col1',N'row2col2')
insert into @p1 values(N'row3col1',N'row3col2')
insert into @p1 values(N'row4col1',N'row4col2')
insert into @p1 values(N'row5col1',N'row5col2')

exec StoredProcedureName @MyParam=@p1
```

My question is, how secure against SQL injection attacks is this, given that the insert statements are not parameterized? I tried the most trivial attack against it, and the quotes were properly escaped, but has anyone run an exhaustive test, or is there something else going on here that would protect me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about SQL Injection attacks with TVPs.

> This seems like a bunch of singleton
>   calls  but it's not.  As my colleage
>   Keith Elmore at Microsoft CSS pointed
>   out, that is just the convention used
>   to allow the data to be displayed or
>   copied/pasted into a query window and
>   run.  The TVP isn’t actually
>   implemented in that way—the rows are
>   streamed across just like a bulk
>   insert—but it may have led to this
>   impression that it does simple
>   inserts.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/mikecha/archive/2009/08/07/two-fast-ways-to-bulk-insert-client-generated-data-to-sql-database.aspx

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I looked and looked, but I couldn't find anything.